# iOS - Cannot get a DetailDisclosure for a button in the callout

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, calloutview

I am using Swift with iOS 9.   No matter what button type I select, except ContactAdd, only and info icon is rendered.  I am trying to get a DetailDisclosure icon for the right side of the callout in a mapview.  Here is the code:

```
    let rightButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
    rightButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created a pin yet? Try adding the button `.DetailDisclosure` to the `pinView`

```
var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? 
pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
```

**Update**
This worked for me

```
let identifier = "pin"
var view: MKPinAnnotationView
view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
view.canShowCallout = true
view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure) as UIView
```

Comment: Sorry.  Let me provide the entire method.  I believe the pin is being created properly...

Comment: `code` func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
  {
        let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: noseyesAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

        annotationView.pinTintColor = noseyesAnnotation.color

        annotationView.canShowCallout = true

        let rightButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);

        rightButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton; `code`

Comment: @Darrell, try to add comments/update your original question instead of adding new answers. This code above gives you an icon of (!) when you click an POI. If you can´t see this then you have other issues in your code, try to replace your code inside your func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? with the code I have provided in my updated answer.

Comment: I believe may misunderstanding was that I expected a ">" icon and not a "?" as the disclosure

Answer (score 0):

```
@user2893289
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
 {
    let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: noseyesAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
    annotationView.pinTintColor = noseyesAnnotation.color
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    let rightButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    return annotationView
}
```